# BaseCamp API doesn't provide JSON responses

Tags: android, json, restful-url, basecamp

I am trying to implement Basecamp API in Android application. I am trying to rename the url from `.xml` extension to `.json`. It is working fine for some of the web services like peoples, Companies etc.

But when I try to get the json response of the particular  company then it is giving me response in xml, though I am requesting for json.

like

```
String url =  "https://"+ domain +"/companies/" + companyId +".json"
```

and also Same for

```
"https://" + domain + "/projects/count.json".
```

Also I am trying to implement for below links it is not giving me result in json(is it giving blank response) but if I change the extension from `.json` to `.xml` then it is working fine for me and giving me response in XML

```
 1. "https://" + domain + "/projects/" + projectid +
    "/calendar_entries/milestones.json" 

 2. "https://" + domain + "/todo_lists.json?responsible_party=" + id

 3. "https://" + domain + "/projects/" + projectId +
    "/calendar_entries.json"

 4. "https://" + domain + "/projects/" + projectId +
    "/categories.xml?type=post"
```

I am using a Rest full API for connection with Restful web service.

I don't know why I am not getting json response from the web service.

Please help me out.

Comment: need your help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858098/login-to-new-basecamp-programatically-without-user-intervention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [their API docs](http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/index.shtml), they don't seem to support JSON responses.

> **The Basecamp API is implemented as vanilla XML** over HTTP using all four verbs (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE)

Some routes maybe returning json - probably they're working on json responses & is not rolled out yet. But the docs say it's XML, so you're stuck with XML for now.

Comment: But in the discussion http://groups.google.com/group/37signals-api/browse_thread/thread/edfbf31f61cae4e7.They supports some JSON request.

Comment: @Dharmendra - "we make no guarantees about it". That pretty much sums up my answer too.

Comment: SO Sathya What should I do, work with XML or JSON?I already implemented some services with  JSON so Should I have to change them to XML ?

Comment: @Dharmendra you should change to XML. Until and unless they officially announce json, I wouldn't use it because you never know when they'd make it stop.

Comment: Yes that is the point.I should have to change the JSON to XML.Thanks for your help.:)

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding 'Accept' in the requests headers something like

```
Accept : application/json
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are using Basecamp Classic API which does not support JSON response.

The all-new Basecamp has all-new API supporting REST-style API that uses JSON for serialization and OAuth 2 for authentication. You can find it here (https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api).