# Login to new basecamp programatically [without user intervention]

Tags: basecamp, 37-signals

**What I am trying to do is :**

I am trying to integrate my web application with basecamp. When a user logs in 
to my web application, it should list all tasks/todo's assigned to him/her in 
basecamp.

**What I already have :**

I have admin credentials of basecamp from where I manage all 
products/applications todos, Client Id, Client Secret, ProductName/appName and 
redirect url (available in app. settings)

1. Is it possible to login to basecamp in background/programatically (without 
   user intervention) and get details of all todo's and related information?

   If yes then how?
2. Are the parameters mentioned above enough to do this? If not, then how can 
   I achieve this?

Can anyone please guide me?

I've Googled a lot but could not get a complete solution.

**Links Referred:**

- [HTTPS connection with basic auth result into Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105681/https-connection-with-basic-auth-result-into-unauthorized)
- https://github.com/37signals/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md
- https://github.com/37signals/basecamp-classic-api/blob/master/sections/data_reference.md#person
- https://github.com/mark-hahn/basecamp/blob/master/basecamp.coffee
- http://www.gregaker.net/2012/feb/25/oauth-the-37-signals-api/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to login to basecamp in background/programatically
>   (without user intervention) and get details of all todo's and related
>   information?

Yes it is possible. Just you will have to collect the username, password and domain from the user.

You can find out all the APis from http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/index.shtml
Also for login you will have to deal with https protocol so you will have to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7157404/630668).

> Are the parameters mentioned above enough to do this? If not, then how
>   can I achieve this?

Yes I think these parameters are enough to login. You have required Username, Password and Domain information.

Basecamp provides complete REST APIs in xml format. It has all the methods GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

Don't forget to set request header to `application/xml`.

Hope you will get your answer.